# How can two YAML files use common settings, configuration, build steps or jobs?

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflows in a GitHub repo, one to build and push a docker image to a cloud account for staging when there is a PR request (merge) or push to the staging branch, and then another workflow to build/push a Docker image to a different cloud account to production when there is a PR request (merge from feature branch) or push to the "prod" branch.

In these two workflows, there is a lot of common configuration.

I want to run the same tests on each Docker container.

It seems like there should be a way to inherit or have a parent YAML that each of these could refer to or use in common.

I do not want to have the same code in both as it is maintenance overhead.

With GitHub Actions, how is this typically handled?

Comment: Flip it around, have _reusable workflows_ or _custom actions_ that take the things that vary as inputs.